# cache problem iusse by adding dynamic product detail tab

Tags: magento2, cache

I developed module to adding dynamic product tab in product detail page shown in pic below.
but one issue arrive when we add new tab from admin-side then it doesn't at frontend of product detail page without cache clear.
after clearing cache it show.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for magento. Product page is cached, so any change you want to see, you need to clear cache. No other way. Unless you do some JS loading using ajax (that is not cached), add that content with JS, but that is too much I think. Also can disable product page caching, but that is worst solution.

Comment: true,
but i am finding how to call plugin method by JS.

Answer (score 0):

**This is default magento flow and it's very good approach for speed.**

Page is cached in magento cache, so changes doesn't reflect until you clear cache.

you can disable cache for your page through adding  `cacheable="false"` in your xml

But I never suggest it because it will bypass whole page from caching and you will realize your product page speed is decreased/slow.

Comment: I know it is default magento flow and cacheable="false" in xml is not a good approach.

Comment: I am finding solution to call plugin class by js.
I doesn't know it is possible or not.